# Django: Filter for many to many field gives too many answers?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

have the following four models

**Measurement:**

```
class Measurement(models.Model):
    config = models.ForeignKey(MeasurementConfig)   
    energy = models.ForeignKey(Energy)   
    dose = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=9, blank=True, null=True)
```

**MeasurementConfig**

```
class MeasurementConfig(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    linac = models.ForeignKey(Linac)
```

**Linac**

```
class Linac(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Type)
    energies = models.ManyToManyField(Energy)
```

**Energy**

```
class Energy(models.Model):
    value = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(EnergyCategory)
```

Now I want to get all the dose measurements from the Measurement model for a specific Linac and Energy.

I have used the following code to get these:

```
linac = get_object_or_404(Linac, name=linacname)   

# Get all the energies for the specified linac
measurementconfigs = MeasurementConfig.objects.filter(linac=linac)
identifications = []
for measurementconfig in measurementconfigs:
    identifications.append(measurementconfig.identification)
config = get_object_or_404(MeasurementConfig, identification=identifications[0])
energies = config.linac.energies.all()

# Get the measurements
energymeasurements = []    
for energy in energies:
    measurements = Measurement.objects.filter(config__linac=linac).filter(config__linac__energies__exact=energy)
    energymeasurements.append(measurements)
```

What I expect energymeasurements to look like is like this:

```
energymeasurements = [(Measurements_**Energy1**), (Measurements_**Energy2**), (Measurements_**EnergyN**)]
```

Where N is the amount of energies

But what I get is this:

```
energymeasurements = [(Measurements_**ALLEnergies1**), (Measurements_**ALLEnergies2**), (Measurements_**ALLEnergiesN**)]
```

Where N is the amount of energies.

So I expect that the query I make gets all the measurements for the specific energy specified by the loop. But instead I get the measurements for all the energies. 
I've already tried it without the loop by using only the id of a specific energy, the same problem occurs.

I know the problem is in the query, but I can't find out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your objective:

> Now I want to get all the dose measurements from the Measurement model for a specific Linac and Energy.

My approach:

1. Get the Linac record.
2. Use the many-to-many link table to get the appropriate Energy record.
3. Get all MeasurementConfig records linked to the Linac record.
4. For each MeasurementConfig records, get all Measurement records; use the Energy record to filter this record set.

In the code you posted, it looks like you're trying to filter the Measurements record set on a link that doesn't exist, according to the models you specified.

```
# Get the measurements
energymeasurements = []    
for energy in energies:
    measurements = Measurement.objects.filter(config__linac=linac).filter(config__linac__energies__exact=energy)
    energymeasurements.append(measurements)
```

A Measurement isn't linked to a Linac, so I think this is why you're not getting the result you expect.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I still don't fully understand why it isn't working. But that is probably due to my lack of knowledge of databases and how they work.
However I did get it to work by the steps you described above. 

Maybe I can help you out someday in the future, thanks!